# If $\frac{a}{|z_2-z_3|}=\frac{b}{|z_3-z_1|}=\frac{c}{|z_1-z_2|}$, then why is $\frac{a^2}{z_2-z_3}+\frac{b^2}{z_3-z_1}+\frac{c^2}{z_1-z_2}=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $\dfrac{a}{|z_2-z_3|}=\dfrac{b}{|z_3-z_1|}=\dfrac{c}{|z_1-z_2|}$, then why is $\dfrac{a^2}{z_2-z_3}+\dfrac{b^2}{z_3-z_1}+\dfrac{c^2}{z_1-z_2}=0$?

This is a complex number property given in my book but the derivation is not given. How do I get this result? I refer to the chapter complex numbers of the book 39 years chapterwise topicwise solved papers by Arihant.

Comment: Please read the advice at "How to ask a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . This question, and another you have asked, don't meet the standards we look for.  The most obvious point is that you referred to a book - which book are you looking at? Which page, theorem, or exercise? The second issue is that, as the link above explains, we discourage questions that simply pose a problem.

Comment: One concrete strategy, if you cannot prove the inequality, might be to try replacing $z_1$ and/or $z_2$ with 1, proving the simpler inequality, and then trying to generalize your proof.

Comment: @CarlMummert I have edited the two questions, I actually did not mention it earlier as I didn't think it likely that many people would have the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\frac{a}{|z_2-z_3|}=\frac{b}{|z_3-z_1|}=\frac{c}{|z_1-z_2|}=k$,
then $a=k|z_2-z_3|,b=k|z_3-z_1|,c=k|z_1-z_2|$.
So $$\frac{a^2}{z_2-z_3}=k^2(\bar{z_2}-\bar{z_3});$$
$$\frac{b^2}{z_3-z_1}=k^2(\bar{z_3}-\bar{z_1});$$
$$\frac{c^2}{z_1-z_2}=k^2(\bar{z_1}-\bar{z_2}).$$
This implies 
$$\frac{a^2}{z_2-z_3}+\frac{b^2}{z_3-z_1}+\frac{c^2}{z_1-z_2}=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $z_2-z_3=ka e^{i\alpha}$, $z_3-z_1=kbe^{i\beta}$ and $z_1-z_2=kce^{i\gamma}$ where $k\ne 0$

\begin{align}
  ka e^{i\alpha}+kbe^{i\beta}+kce^{i\gamma} &=
  (z_2-z_3)+(z_3-z_2)+(z_1-z_2) \\
  a e^{i\alpha}+be^{i\beta}+ce^{i\gamma} &= 0 \tag{1} \\
  \frac{a^2}{z_2-z_3}+\frac{b^2}{z_3-z_1}+\frac{c^2}{z_1-z_2} &=
  \frac{a}{ke^{i\alpha}}+\frac{b}{ke^{i\beta}}+\frac{c}{ke^{i\gamma}} \\
  &= \frac{a e^{-i\alpha}+be^{-i\beta}+ce^{-i\gamma}}{k} \\
\end{align}

Equating real and imaginary parts for $(1)$, the result follows.